# Loading JS libraries and using them right ater they are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am looking for a clean way to use libraries (such as jQuery, Knockout) in my HTML document.

In order to do that, I include links to CDN or to downloaded libraries in `<script src=...` element.

But often I stumble upon such problem: I have JS script, where I use `ko.applyBindings` (or other library-specific method or symbols, such as `$`) and I get errors, which I solve by putting all that "library-specific" code in `window.onload` event handler.

So I started wondering, what is good practice of doing that? It feels quite good and I don't see any problems with my solution so far, but I am uncertain about it.

Also, are sripts for our page loaded synchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<script>` tags are loaded synchronously by default [(docs here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async) and in the order they are listed in the HTML. This means that they will be executed in the same order they are in in the HTML.

So ideally, the way to handle this would be to put the scripts in order of dependency, with the dependent scripts last and libraries first.  This avoids having to use listeners and additional code to wait for all scripts to load.

Hope this helps!  Let me know if I should clarify more.

Comment: That said... sometimes this isn't possible due to using a CMS or something else where you don't have control of the order that scripts are listed in.  In this case, your idea is a good solution to the issue.